# How can i transpose an .csv into a sql table with an SSIS Job?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

i want to transpose a SQL table into the following format. Can someone tell me how this is possible? I'am new in this topic, so i dont know so much about that. I already tried with the Pivot function of SSIS but i wont work.

Can someone please tell me an SQL Statement or an SSIS Job to help me with this Problem?

[image: Red marked table: How i get the Data Green marked table: How i need the Data]

Comment: If you have the red and want the green, have a look to the SQL Server unpivot. If it is the other way, do a pivot.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want to start in red and go to green or the opposite.

Either way, You are in need of [PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) functions.

Let's create some test tables to mimic your data

```
create table #_base
(
    Dt_ref  datetime 
,   Val     float
)

insert into #_base
values
 ('2018-12-16 01:00:00.000', 36.96)
,('2018-12-16 02:00:00.000', 38.81)
,('2018-12-16 03:00:00.000', 38.1)
,('2018-12-16 04:00:00.000', 38.58)
,('2018-12-16 05:00:00.000', 38.23)
,('2018-12-16 06:00:00.000', 38.42)
,('2018-12-17 01:00:00.000', 96.96)
,('2018-12-17 02:00:00.000', 98.81)
,('2018-12-17 03:00:00.000', 98.1)
,('2018-12-17 04:00:00.000', 98.58)
,('2018-12-17 05:00:00.000', 98.23)
,('2018-12-17 06:00:00.000', 98.42)

select * from #_base
```

Let's create your Green dataset

```
select  cast(Dt_ref as date) as Day
    ,   datepart (hour,Dt_ref) as Hour
    ,   Val 
into #_base_green
from #_base

select * from #_base_green
```

If you want to go from Green to Red just PIVOT

```
select  Day
    ,   [1] as Hour1
    ,   [2] as Hour2
    ,   [3] as Hour3
    ,   [4] as Hour4
    ,   [5] as Hour5
    ,   [6] as Hour6
into #_result_red
from #_base_green p
pivot (
    sum(val)
    for Hour in 
    (   [1] 
    ,   [2] 
    ,   [3] 
    ,   [4] 
    ,   [5] 
    ,   [6] ) 
) as pvt

select * from #_result_red
```

From Red to Green, UNPIVOT

```
select * 
into #_base_red
from #_result_red

select * from #_base_red

select  
        dateadd(hh, cast(substring(hours,5,6) as int), cast(day as datetime))
    ,   value
into #_result_green
from
(
    select Day,      Hour1
                    ,Hour2
                    ,Hour3
                    ,Hour4
                    ,Hour5
                    ,Hour6
    from #_base_red
) p
unpivot (value for Hours in (Hour1
                    ,Hour2
                    ,Hour3
                    ,Hour4
                    ,Hour5
                    ,Hour6) 
) as unpvt

select * from #_result_green
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `unpivot` transform component

[image]

you need to double click on Unpivot to select columns which is going to be transformed to rows